# how to move files based on birth time in hadoop

Tags: linux, shell, unix, hadoop, move

I have some 200k files in a folder, i want to organize them based on time of birth(creation time). i wrote the below script but it is way too slow. i want to improve it. how can i do it?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo Input directory is $1
input_directory=$1

## Find those files that are older than a month

inputfiles=$(hadoop fs -ls  $input_directory | sed '1d;s/  */ /g' | cut -d\  -f8)

for filename in $inputfiles
  do
   echo processing $filename

   hadoop fs -test -d  $filename

   lastcommand=$?

   if [ "$lastcommand" == "1" ];then

        year=$(date -d "`hadoop fs -stat $filename`" +%Y)
        month=$(date -d "`hadoop fs -stat $filename`" +%m)

        hadoop fs -test -d $input_directory/$year-$month
        lastcommand2=$?

        [[ "$lastcommand2" == "1" ]] && hadoop fs -mkdir -p $input_directory/$year-$month;

        hadoop fs -mv $filename $input_directory/$year-$month/
    else
        echo not a file
   fi
  done
```

Comment: Cross-post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/468382/how-to-move-files-based-on-birth-time-in-hadoop

Comment: Maybe it's slow because you're invoking a new JVM every time `hadoop` command is executed... Can you not do this entirely in Hadoop Java API?

Comment: i can try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use hadoop filesystem rename command to move the flies and it worked like charm. brought down the time to a minute from hours. thank you